# Rust match Option type get error use of moved value

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and I found piece of code below:

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::io::{Result, Write};

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
pub struct HttpResponse<'a> {
    version: &'a str,
    status_code: &'a str,
    status_text: &'a str,
    headers: Option<HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>>,
    body: Option<String>,
}


impl<'a> Default for HttpResponse<'a> {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {
            version: "HTTP/1.1".into(),
            status_code: "200".into(),
            status_text: "OK".into(),
            headers: None,
            body: None,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a> HttpResponse<'a> {
    pub fn new(
        status_code: &'a str,
        headers: Option<HashMap<&'a str, &'a str>>,
        body: Option<String>,
    ) -> HttpResponse<'a> {
        let mut response: HttpResponse<'a> = HttpResponse::default();
        if status_code != "200" {
            response.status_code = status_code;
        };

        response.headers = match headers {
            Some(_h) => headers, // got error here: Use of moved value 
            // use of partially moved value: `headers` [E0382] 
            // value used here after partial move Note: partial move occurs because value has type `HashMap<&str, &str>`, 
            // which does not implement the `Copy` trait
            None => {
                let mut h = HashMap::new();
                h.insert("Content-Type", "text/html");
                Some(h)
            }
        };

        response.status_text = match response.status_code {
            "200" => "OK".into(),
            "400" => "Bad Request".into(),
            "404" => "Not Found".into(),
            "500" => "Internal Server Error".into(),
            _ => "Not Found".into(),
        };
        response.body = body;

        response
    }
}
```

```
error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `headers`
  --> src/lib.rs:38:25
   |
38 |             Some(_h) => headers, // got error here: Use of moved value 
   |                  --     ^^^^^^^ value used here after partial move
   |                  |
   |                  value partially moved here
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because value has type `HashMap<&str, &str>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

I don't know why I got the "Use of moved value", I think the way called **"moved"** should be something like this:

```rust
    let s1 = String::from("Hello,World");
    let s2 = s1;
```

or you pass variable as parameter to some function.

so, could some explain why I got this error? what is moved here? and why if we change the code with reference, the error disappear(nothing moved?)

```rust
response.headers = match &headers {
```

Comment: You bind `_h` to `headers`, this moves it.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman. thx. I think maybe I should read more post about destructure in rust. and I found it interesting that if the code is ```response.headers = match headers ```, the type of `_h` is `HashMap<&str, &str`, and when using reference ```response.headers = match &headers```  , the type of `_h` is `&HashMap<&str, &str`,  which is also a reference.

Comment: I recommend the `rust-analyzer` plugin for the IDE of your choice, it provides automatic type annotations. Very useful.

Comment: thx , I'm using CLion, yes it has some type highlighting, for example, ```let mut h = HashMap::new();```, it shows the type of h is `HashMap<&str,&str>`, but unfortunately it didn't show the type of `_h` unless I move mouse on it.  XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match`ing something moves it, if matching the object itself. This is just how Rust works. Rust objects aren't copyable by default, so destructuring operations (like `if let` or `match`) destroy the original object to gain access to its contents.

This is easily fixable by `match`ing a reference instead:

```rust
response.headers = match &headers {
    Some(_h) => headers,
    None => {
        let mut h = HashMap::new();
        h.insert("Content-Type", "text/html");
        Some(h)
    }
};
```

Alternatively (and probably preferredly), use the built-in function for exactly your purpose:

```rust
response.headers = headers.or_else(|| {
    let mut h = HashMap::new();
    h.insert("Content-Type", "text/html");
    Some(h)
});
```

Or even shorter:

```rust
response.headers = headers.or_else(|| Some(HashMap::from([("Content-Type", "text/html")])));
```